# How to duplicate object with it's animation then relocate/rotate

Tags: animation

I want to duplicate an object along with it's animation but I want to use the duplicated object(s) somewhere else in the scene. Is this possible? I guess I would need to maintain the animation locally to the duplicated object but not sure how that works.

For example a ball rolling on it's x-axis is duplicated with it's animation. I want to move that duplicated ball so that it is the same animation but rolling on the y-axis.

Comment: sloppy way would be to apply location...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

One way is with a [*DupliGroup*](http://blender.org/manual/modeling/objects/duplication/dupligroup.html):

1. Group your object(s) with <kbd>⎈ Ctrl</kbd><kbd>G</kbd>
2. Add a dupligroup with <kbd>⇧ Shift</kbd><kbd>A</kbd>*> Group Instance >* name of your group.

   This will create an empty which represents the origin point (`0,0,0`) of the space in which the duplicated group resides. By transforming this empty, you can transform the dupligroup:

   [image]

   Dupliobjects use *instancing*, which means this will also be [very memory efficient](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/9209/599).

Answer (score 3):

Duplicate the object in question and then use **Delta Transform** in the object panel. This will displace the object in any axis wanted and retain the original animation.

Answer (score 0):

Relocate an animated object is very easy:

Suppose that you want to offset the position by 3 Blender units on the Z axis:

select it, go to the graph editor, select the blue z location channel, turn on the arrow near to the little phantom in the header (view only selected curve keyframes), toggle A to select all keyframes, G Y 3 Enter.

About setting an x-axis movement transformed in an y-axis movement, you should cut the keyframes from the x location channel, and paste them in the y location channell: I don't think there is this kind of option, you should have a little Python script.
Anyway, selecting both channels, it's very easy to do the job by hand.

AFAIK the location keyframes are always referred to the world, not local.