# Animation Nodes - How to Instance multiple objects/collection

Tags: animation, animation-nodes

I do have some meshes under a Collection and I would like to put them into an Object Instancer while maintaining the original positions (it's a cartoon tree).

Can't find a way to do this.

Thanks!

Comment: Try this: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/33706/how-to-duplicate-object-with-its-animation-then-relocate-rotate

Comment: Instancing a Collection worked out. Not exactly the same workflow as the link, but it works. Now my objects maintain the original position. Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You may use the *Object Instancer* node to instance a group of empties, then you can set their `instance_type` to `COLLECTION` and set their `instance_collection` to whatever collection you want. For instance:

[image: Node Tree]

Comment: This is amazing. Thank you. 
If you have time, can you elaborate a bit more about this setup? 

I instance empties and then trough Object Attribute Output I define some parameters... but where come from those instance_types and instance_collection  inputs? Why the instance_type text input needs to be uppercase? 

Thanks again!

Comment: @DimitriPaiva `instance_types` and `instance_collection ` are just the names of the properties in the python API. Hover over any property and you will see its API name. In this case, I hovered over the properties in the Object->Instancing panel to know their names. Moreover, it being uppercase is also related to how it is defined in the API, string properties are uppercase by convention.

Comment: Thanks @Omar. It was very helpful. Also, sorry about the delay. It has been tough weeks here.

Comment: what i get from instancing a colleciton here is an objects list. is it possible to get access to the child of an instance? Let's say I randomly instance a few collections all over my scene and my master collection has an empty. is it somehow possible to get the emptys world position within each collection?