# How can I reproduce the same mesh many times 9000 (seriously)

Tags: mesh

So, I'm working on a project where I have to create a front panel of an LED light. The front layer is made up of little diamond shaped surface, the light passes through this, and these tiny diamond shaped front panel helps illuminate and spread light evenly across. Anyway, the problem I'm having is that I tried the easiest way i know to create this panel, which is to make it using a plane mesh, and duplicating it. However for the size I needed, I ended up with over 9000, yes over 9000 (9435) separate duplicates put together. It has the look I want, but its impossible to edit or render it out because there is obviously too many of them and blender keeps freezing. So I'm stuck. How can I fix this without blowing up my PC. If anyone knows an alternate way to create this, please help me! :> I would really appreciate it.

[image]

Comment: You just need to do a single diamond and use array modifiers. The beauty of modifiers is that you can switch then on and off to edit.

Comment: How can i do array modifier?

Comment: https://www.blender.org/manual/modeling/modifiers/generate/array.html?highlight=array

Comment: Ok thanks! I will look into using arrays. But will these methods such as using arrays improve rendering and editing speeds? :>

Comment: Using instances also speeds up the viewport and rendering, as well as lowering memory usage and sync time.

Comment: Ok so array and instances both speed up viewport and rendering speeds? Also do you know any instance tutorials that can help? :)

Comment: 45000 (9000*5) verts isn't unrealistically massive for a single object. Try joining all your objects together with Ctrl J, or using an array modifier

Comment: Already had them joined with ctrl+j but was stiill laggy, i will try remaking the whole panel using instances and arrays :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Every time yo find yourself doing the same action over and over, think that there has to be a better way, either by instancing, using arrays or scripts to save you from tedious tasks.

In this case creating a large number of copies of the same object can be done with the **[Array Modifier](https://www.blender.org/manual/modeling/modifiers/generate/array.html?highlight=array)**

Create your base object.

Add an Array Modifier.

That will duplicate the object however many times you want it. The default is on the X axis (but you can modify that).

Then add a second array to duplicate however many times you need in the Y axis (or any other axis you need)

[image]

Comment: For other alternatives to deal with very large number of instances see this: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/9206/what-techniques-have-been-used-to-repeat-geometry-or-other-detail-to-the-infinit/9209#9209

Comment: Thankyou so much! I will do this. Would it be better to to make instance of the mesh object first and then   use array modifier to speed up render and viewport or the other way around?  Or does it not matter ?

Comment: read the [link on my comment](http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/9206/what-techniques-have-been-used-to-repeat-geometry-or-other-detail-to-the-infinit/9209#9209). Instancing will use less resources.