# Create a periodic object

Tags: modeling

I am drawing periodical objects with 10µm width with 10µm distance. I would normally use duplicate but it goes for around 2.5 cm. So is there any tool to create periodical objects?

Any help appreciated.

Comment: array modifier ? but I don't know if you know about that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use an array modifier.  Select the object you want to duplicate, and click on the wrench icon in the properties panel.  Then click *Add Modifier*, and select *Array*.  Then in the tab it brings up, select *Relative Offset*, and change it to what you want.  Finally, change *Count* to the number of duplicates you want.  Sorry that I can't upload any screenshots, but I'm rendering right now.

Comment: Thank you I also realized that my memory can't afford that much objects...

Comment: For an efficient way to make instances using dupliobjects read [this answer](http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/9206/what-techniques-have-been-used-to-repeat-geometry-or-other-detail-to-the-infinit/9209#9209)