# Instancing Objects infinte ammount of time?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, eevee-render-engine, scene, instances

I have modeled a modular kit wich consist of 9 objects and togethter around 1127 faces. Togethter places with some instancing of the objects i get one big Module. This Module consists of two floor pieces (all togethter around 25 objects, polycount is still 1127). I have to instance this Module now over 4000 times in my scene.

Shift-D is not an option since it creates a new object and only raises the polycount. Same goss for the array modifier.
Alt-D increases the memory aswell after a time, not the polycount but the procedural shaders are raising the memory. (I guess...)

Either way the viewport gets really laggy...

Procedural shaders are required to randomize location and effect ammount of the material on each new instance. So i cant use Image texture Based shaders.

According to this Post there is a Methode with duplication, but where is that in blender 2.8?
[What techniques have been used to repeat geometry or other detail to the infinite horizon?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/9206/what-techniques-have-been-used-to-repeat-geometry-or-other-detail-to-the-infinit/9209#9209)

Any ideas or methods to solve this problem?

Comment: In 2.8 it's not called Duplication anymore but Instancing, you need to create a mesh and the object will be duplicated on its vertices or faces depending on the option you choose. But I'm not sure you save memory compared to alt D, and also maybe you should find a trick to lower down the amount of objects in your scene, depending on your storyboard, for example you could create a low-poly version of your object when close shots are not needed

Comment: thanks for the reply, thats exactly what i did. I took my modular kit and parented it to a new mesh. I used an array modifier to offset the mesh. and saved a ton of memory in the viewport.