# What method is more efficient for making duplicate of an object: mirror it with modifier or instancing it?

Tags: rendering, workflow, memory-management

I wonder what method i should use for making copies of original object, what is more memory/render efficient: mirror my object with modifies - "Array" or "Mirror" or instancing my object with Alt+D?

Comment: Related - http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/19736/how-can-i-save-memory-in-cycles-when-i-have-a-lot-of-duplicates. The modifiers are good in order to have geometry for other modifiers but not good for memory usage etc. You can use instancing with `Alt`+`D` still dupliframes will save more memory if there're lot of duplicates.

Comment: Thank you. I assume Mirror modifier also does not create an instance, just like array modifier. U gona use instancing in this case.

Comment: @MrZak What are dupliframes?

Comment: @AnsonSavage see https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/editors/3dview/object/properties/duplication/dupliframes.html. Note to ask a question if you have a question, here's also question on BSE https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/510/how-can-i-duplicate-a-mesh-along-a-curve