# How can I link the mesh data of several objects so they all use the same?

Tags: linked-data

I have alot (like 50) duplicated meshes. i used SHIFT-D to duplicate the objects ,but then read that ALT-D saves memory. is there a way to link the mesh data (like using ALT-D) after i have used the wrong duplicate? attempting to go back and use ALT-D would take a long time.

The meshes i duplicated are all the same shape and size and only have different rotations.

Comment: Use Ctrl+L > Object Data. See also https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/51128/file-optimization-duplicate-or-linked-duplicate for resources optimization info

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Select the objects you want to transform and then shift select the object that you want to clone to make it the [**Active Object**](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/editors/3dview/object/editing/transform/control/pivot_point/active_element.html?highlight=active%20object).

Press the space bar and type "link data".
(or press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd> and select "Object Data", or use the menu Objects>Make Links Object Data)

The selected objects will then use the data from the active one.

[image]

Comment: Is there a method to only copy the mesh data and not copy the materials?