# Make a physical clone of an object and modifiy all clones at once?

Tags: modeling

Is it possible to clone an object multiple times and then modify the original so all the clones modify at the same time? To be sure, I dont want to duplicate and modify each object one by one.

Comment: Possible duplicate of: [How can I link the mesh data of several objects so they all use the same?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/86900/how-can-i-link-the-mesh-data-of-several-objects-so-they-all-use-the-same/86904#86904)

Comment: Oh! That's exactly what im looking for, but in other words, thx for the reference!!

Comment: isn't alt D what you want? and if you want to make a copy unique, press U > Object & Data

Comment: I want to be able to edit a mesh and all his clones change at the same time, so no need to edit each meshes.