# Emulate cad-blocks in Blender

Tags: modeling, objects, displacement

Let's say I want to have multiple identical copies of the same object (e.g. a piece of furniture modelled as a mesh) within a blend-file. But I want those copies to be connected in such a way that when I change or re-model something in the original object all the copies change accordingly so that the copies always stay identical, yet freely distributable within the 3D space.

Within a CAD software like AutoCad this is usually accomplished through the use of something called a "block".

In Blender terms this could maybe be described as similar to what the Array modifier does, except that the copies can be freely distributed throughout the file.

Anybody have an idea on how to accomplish this?

Maybe there is an obvious solution to this that I have overlooked. In any event thanks for any help, which is greatly appreciated!

Comment: From description seems that you search for linked duplicates https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/51128/file-optimization-duplicate-or-linked-duplicate

Comment: Mr Zak, that actually seems to be it, thanks! I still have to play around with it a bit, but for the time being this looks like what I'm looking for. Appreciate it!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Sketchup-like components (case study) - is it in? or even feasible?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/47295/sketchup-like-components-case-study-is-it-in-or-even-feasible)