# How to make blend file take up less space

Tags: modeling, edit-mode

Some of my models on my computer are taking up around 400-500 MB and I want to shed some space on my computer. I tried deleting objects and checking for animation data but the best I could get taken off was about 20 MB. How can I get a model to take up s few space as possible?

Comment: Related: https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/51128/

Answer (score 3):

A few things come to mind. These affect not only filesize, but also performance.

- Keep modifiers procedural as long as you can (Subdivision Surface, Array, Mirror, etc. Basically any modifier that adds geometry.)
- Use linked duplicates, instancing and collection instances whenever you can. Instances don't increase filesize and are also better performance wise.

*Procedural Modifiers - filesize 650KB*

[image]

*Applied Modifiers - filesize 20MB (30x increase)*

[image]

Answer (score 2):

### Use the *Compress* option

When you save your blend file, click on the "gear" icon (or press <kbd>N</kbd>), then check *Compress*.

[image]

The file will take less disk space (50% less in many cases, and sometimes even less) ; but it will be a bit slower to save and open it.