# Why does Blender slow down when I duplicate a model repeatedly?

Tags: modeling, performance

[image]

Why does Blender slow down when I duplicate a model repeatedly, as in the above screenshot?

Comment: What do you mean by " repeated versions of the models"?

Comment: If repeated versions = make more copies of model, than the answer is easy: more models = more geometry = more system load.

Comment: Have you tried using the Array modifier instead?

Comment: related: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/9206/what-techniques-have-been-used-to-repeat-geometry-or-other-detail-to-the-infinit and http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/19736/how-can-i-save-memory-in-cycles-when-i-have-a-lot-of-duplicates

Answer (score 1):

Blender's viewport is a more or less simplified 2D representation of what your 3D scene looks like from a certain point of view.

This representation needs to get updated in real-time (if possible) if you rotate a scene and that update needs to be calculated by your GPU as well as your CPU.

As Shubol3D already hinted, duplicating a model also duplicates geometry. Even further, if you have assigned materials and modifiers, they get duplicated as well.

Mathematically every vertex in your scene is described by three vectors, x,y and z. But there is more data behind a vertex than just the geometrical coordinates. Color and light values are only two of them. Imagine a long list of those values in a spread sheet. The more geometry, the longer the spread sheet, the more time it takes for your hardware to update the information that needs to be changed to display your scene.

If this explanation answers your question, please mark it as "accepted".