# How can I make my file light weight?

Tags: modeling, performance

I'm making a fort and I have made a quarter of it to mirror later. I started building with the default cube. And until I make complete model its 210 MB heavy file lagging much. I have to mirror and make the complete fort. Later I have to make surrounding etc. I do not think it will support to make the surrounding its lagging mean time. How can I make a light weight model which I can access much faster? With the model I have made can I make it light weight by scaling down or any other method which can make my file much lighter to work faster? Any suggestions?

### The model I'm working on

[image: The model I'm working on]

Comment: it's difficult to help you without understanding if your mesh is actually worth 210 MB. It seems quite detailed, imho, but not THAT much perhaps. Your attached image is quite small and also lacks info about how many vertices it has, for a start. Also a (high res) edit mode view could help to spot possible enhancements... you obviously already checked duplicates, etc.?

Comment: @m.ardito verts 2,732,236 & faces 2,218,063 with objects 153

Comment: If you link the mesh data of identical objects you can't reduce your .blend file size significantly but this won't really help with the lagging.  Make sure you don't have any unnecessary subsurface modifiers like on the domes.

Comment: @LukasValine I have tried that but i when exporting to obj file it hang or blender kick me to desktop

Comment: Yeah, .obj doesn't support linked meshes (as far as I know) so every duplicate object would be represented multiple times.  If you posted the .blend I couple probably help more.

Comment: @LukasValine Above image attached in the question is the same link file so any good solution. to export .obj file

Answer (score 2):

You have to work in segments, layers and sometimes different blend files linked together.

For such large models it makes no sense to have the whole object loaded at once. Split it in smaller chunks that you can work separately.

Use layers not to have all of the geometry visible at all times. Objects that are hidden save them on a different file and link them only when you need them.

If you are doing the detail of a doorknob, for example, you don't need the towers or any of the landscape.

Think of what is your final goal for this scene. Objects that are not going to be seeing in detail in the final product can be rough and don't need as many vertices as those that are meant to be features prominently.

Most importantly you need to start thinking of a strategy to render (if you are making images) or to split it in to much smaller and manageable parts for it to work on a game (if you are creating assets).

Unless you have supercomputing power at your disposal (which I doubt judging from your post) You need to fragment your scene.  Close to 3 million faces with no textures yet is a lot for an average computer.

Reality has to sink in at some point and you have to realize that blender can deal vast amounts of information, but your computing power is limited, and I think you are getting close to the max.

Try to decimate the geometry, use the minimum amount of subdivision that you can get away with. Use instances instead of duplicating objects (see these links: [How can I save memory in cycles when I have a lot of duplicates?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/19736/how-can-i-save-memory-in-cycles-when-i-have-a-lot-of-duplicates) and [What techniques have been used to repeat geometry or other detail to the infinite horizon?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/9206/what-techniques-have-been-used-to-repeat-geometry-or-other-detail-to-the-infinit/9209#9209))

Plan ahead so that your scene can be rendered: https://www.blenderguru.com/articles/how-to-render-a-complex-scene-without-crashing

Answer (score 1):

You can use compression to make your .blend file significantly smaller.
This can be done by going to `File->Save As...` and then enabling `Compress` on the left side of the screen:
[image]

Comment: That will certainly save on disk space, but how will it help his lag?

Answer (score 0):

As for reducing file size... modifiers use less space than raw verts... however for being able to reduce lag try duplicate the mesh and make a low poly proxy version... then move the original to a different layer so it's no longer in the viewport this will give you a rough guide for use when animating

Comment: making proxy can i export .obj file