# Array object in straight line but rotate object on z axis

Tags: modifiers

So how would I do that I have an object which I want to array in straight line or a slightly curved path (~10 iterations) but I also need that every iteration is rotated for lets say 30 degrees along z axis, what kind of black magic I need to perform to achieve this I tried using empty and rotate it on z but it makes array circular even when I use curve modifier as well. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

**Dupliframes Method:**

The first step is to keyframe the location of desired object at the origin at the first frame (0 or 1). Then we will add a keyframe 10 frames from our first, since we want 10 iterations, at location (5,0,0) and key a rotation of 300 degrees since we would like each iteration to be rotated 30 degrees from the previous (300 = 30 degrees each iteration * 10 frames). In the curve editor we want to make sure that we're using linear interpolation (select keys and press 'T'). This makes sure that the iterations will be evenly spaced. In the Object propeties tab, find Duplication and select frames. Since we only want 10 iterations we will end at frame 10 (It may look correct if left to 100, you will have extra meshes in the same location as the last iteration. Finally when happy with the result we can convert the dulpliobjects to real objects with Ctrl-Shift-A, and Ctrl-J if desired.

[image]
[image]

Comment: Nice answer... but I guess the OP may want a rotation in an axis _not_ coincident with the array offset?

Comment: Yeah, this doesn't actually work because I want them arrayed in straight line from let's say on x axis 0-5, this solution works if I want them to array vertically or vertically in spring shape. What I need is simple array with just rotation on Z in local coordinates and array would go straight in x axis, hope you can understand me.

Comment: Sorry for not understanding at first. I've edited my post with hopefully the correct answer to your question.

Comment: Here's also a good post explaining why the array modifier isn't an appropriate use for this case. https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/21619/69233